# In my react app I am importing mobile styles that are being overridden by general stylesheet

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my App.js I have the following imports:

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles/App.css';
import './styles/mobile.css';
```

in `styles/App.css` I have:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

in `styles/mobile.css` I have:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

In my developer tools I am seeing the mobile styles are being overridden: [image]

I thought that if I import the mobile stylesheet under the general stylesheet that the mobile would take precedence, I have used this in other projects and it seemed to work fine. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media query styles and usual styles have the same [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) which means `h1` inside and outside media queries are similar selectors

In this case, it will check top to bottom in your style declaration (the bottom one will override the top one). You can check the below example

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}

h1 {
  color: blue; /* Get applied */
}
```

```html
<h1>Testing</h1>
```

To fix it, you can change your styles' position declaration

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
  h1 {
    color: red; /* Get applied */
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Testing</h1>
```

If you cannot control your styles' declaration because of your code compilation, you can add another selector to increase the specificity value.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
  body h1 { /* Added `body` here */
    color: red; /* Get applied */
  }
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Testing</h1>
```

As for your case

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles/App.css';
import './styles/mobile.css';
```

Your style imports may be interfered during compilation, and we won't be sure they will have the same style positions as your imports. I used to face a similar bug, my styles were working well in my localhost, but after uglifying/compressing styles, the style positions got changed without my notice.

I'd suggest that in most cases, we should rely on selectors that will help you to have better code visibility and avoid unexpected styles' applications.

---

You also can use [`!important`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) to have the same effect, but I'd not recommend it. `!important` will override all your selector checks, and it will cause more problems when you have many styles applied on the same selector.

Comment: so how does this work with the way I have imported my files? By placing the mobile stylesheets import under the general stylesheets import aren't I doing what you have explained? or am I mistaken?

Comment: @DylanLittle as for your case, your style imports may be interfered during compilation, and we won't be sure they will have the same style positions as your imports. I used to face a similar bug, my styles were working well in my localhost, but after uglifying/compressing styles, the style positions got changed without my notice, and I had to spend hours for debugging. In most cases, we should rely on selectors that will help you to have better code visibility.

Comment: It's really interesting. Sounds good, i'll probably just rely on selectors then. Could you do me a favor and throw that comment into the answer, and i'll mark it. feel free to delete the comment afterwords. Or not, however u wanna do it.

Comment: @DylanLittle I added our discussion part in my answer too :D. By the way, I'm not sure 100% about your setup, but you can see your styles' applications in HTML. They may have some hints for you to narrow down where the true problem is.